# Convert given value of contourf color to rgb code

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, contourf

I created a 2D contourf plot with viridis color scheme in bounds vmin=0,vmax=4. Here is the code:

```
ax.contourf(xi/d,yi/d,data/d,12,vmin=0,vmax=4,cmap=vs.viridis(),aspect='equal')
```

Now I have from another calculation a data point at a specific location with data=3.5 and want to superimpose this to the contour using a colored circle patch.

So how can I add the rgb color information to the circle within the range and used colorscheme of my contourf

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` instance to do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=4)
cmap = plt.cm.viridis

mycolor = cmap(norm(3.5))
print mycolor
# (0.67848900000000001, 0.86374200000000001, 0.189503, 1.0)
```

Note, if the colormap has been imported from a different file, then it will need to be registered with `matplotlib` first before this works. For example:

```
import myviridisfile as vs
plt.register_cmap(name='viridis', cmap=vs.viridis)
```

Comment: Thanks it is working, unfortunately not for viridis colormap. Error message is: viridis() takes no arguments (1 given)

But I love this colormap*g*

Comment: If you aren't using `matplotlib 1.5.0`, and have imported `viridis` from another file, you may need to register it first: `plt.register_cmap(name='viridis', cmap=vs.viridis)`

Comment: maybe my question should be *how* are you importing `viridis`?

Comment: Dam that was fast, yes I imported it from another file and the last step was the solution. Thank thanks thanks

Comment: Ok last question, how can I color with this results a a scatter point, tried to convert it to hex but it did not work